# Adjusting sizes to calculate a new weighted average, but keeping the same total size...

Tags: linear-algebra

I have prices $p_i$, sizes $s_i$, with average weighted price $A=\frac{\sum(p_i s_i)}{\sum(s_i)}$

I want to calculate $s'_i$, such that

$\sum(s'_i) = \sum(s_i)$

to give a desired new average weighted price

$B = \frac{\sum(p_i  s'_i)} { \sum(s'_i)}$

What is the best way to do this?

Would it be possible to solve this with a linear relationship:

$s'_i = ms_i+c$.

(EDITING IN RESPONSE TO ISCO'S ACCEPTED ANSWER)

For people lacking algebra skills, this can be solved using Sympy, which confirms the accepted answer.

```
from sympy import symbols, Sum

m = symbols("m")
n = symbols("n")
c = symbols("c")

sum_p = symbols("sum_p")
sum_ps = symbols("sum_ps")
sum_s = symbols("sum_s")
A = symbols("A")
B = symbols("B")

eqn1 = 1-n*c/sum_s - m
eqn2 = (1/A)*(B - c*sum_p/sum_s) - m


# Solve the equations
solution = solve((eqn1, eqn2), (m, c))

# Print the solutions
print("Solutions:")
print("m =", solution[m])
print("c =", solution[c])
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly your problem is actually rather under-specified.

Trivially rearranging your equation involving $B$ you have

$$
\sum (p_i s'_i) = B \sum s'_i
$$

and you want $\sum s'_i$ to be equal to $\sum s_i$ therefore

$$
\sum (p_i s'_i) = B \sum s_i
$$

Assuming you already have all of the sizes $s_i$, or even just their sum, the right-hand-side here is just some known number. So your problem is reduced to finding any vector $s'$ such that the dot product with the price vector $p$ is some desired scalar value. If there is only one (non-zero) price then the required size is trivial to calculate, and if there are multiple then there are infinite possible solutions. You could set $n-1$ of the sizes to any nonsense and on the last one pick the correct size to get the target scalar product.

I would guess that in the real world there are some constraints, such as all prices are positive, and maybe all sizes too, depending on what you are doing. If you are working on some kind of trading system, perhaps what you really want is to minimize trading volume by calculating some $s'$ which is as close as possible to $s$, while still targeting the new $B$.

If you decide that you do wish to make the relationship linear or similar, you may wish to ask a new question about a least-squares solution or linear programming or something like that.

**Edit after comment discussion:**

After you asked for help understanding further, I tried to put together a linear least-squares solution for you to estimate $m$ and $c$, but when I worked through the algebra an exact solution fell out. I guess because you only care about the sums it works.

You want the sum of the sizes to be equal so

$$
\sum s_i = \sum s'_i = \sum (m s_i + c) = m \sum s_i + c \sum 1 = m \sum s_i + n c
$$

which we can use to get our first equation for $m$ in terms of $c$

$$
m = 1 - \frac {n c} {\sum s_i}
$$

You want the new average weighted price to be

$$
B = \frac {\sum (p_i s'_i)} {\sum s'_i} = \frac {\sum (p_i (m s_i + c))} {\sum s_i} = \frac {m \sum (p_i s_i)} {\sum s_i} + \frac {c \sum p_i} {\sum s_i} = m A + \frac {c \sum p_i} {\sum s_i}
$$

which we can use to get our second equation for $m$ in terms of $c$

$$
m = \frac 1 A \left(B - \frac {c \sum p_i} {\sum s_i}\right)
$$

We have two equations and two variables so solving is simple enough

$$
m = \frac {n B - \sum p_i} {n A - \sum p_i} \\\\
c = \frac {(A-B) \sum s_i} {n A - \sum p_i}
$$

and then you can trivially find all $s'_i$.

Comment: would using the constraints s'_i= mis_i+c force it to have a unique solution?

Comment: You can impose those constraints if you wish. Then the problem will be over-specified rather than under-specified. Basically there is not necessarily any $m$ and $c$ producing a vector $s'_i$ which exactly satisfies your target $B$, and generally there won't be.

At that point it is an optimization or "best-fit" problem. Your two options are either to minimize the error in $B$ for an exactly linear relationship, in which case you may want to look into linear programming, or to satisfy your $B$ exactly but allow your sizes to only approximate this relationship, using least-squares or similar.

Comment: I would guess you want the latter of these, since you probably care about the average weighted price more than an exactly linear relationship, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, yes it doesn't need to be a perfect method. Please help me understand why this is over specified? I'm a bit rusty in this area.

Comment: Over-specified just means that you have more equations than free variables. You suggested a relationship described by $s'_i = m s_i + c$, so you would have 2 free variables, $m$ and $c$. The new sizes $s'_i$ are not free variables, if you decide to set things up this way, because they are fully determined by $m$, $c$ and the existing sizes $s_i$. Now, imagine you have 3 prices, and 3 existing sizes, and want to get 3 new sizes which will allow you to target the correct $B$. You will not generally be able to get all 3 "outputs" as you want them because you only have 2 "inputs" that you control.

Comment: Ok, the edited answer should now explain how to do it. I didn't expect that to be possible without some optimization or estimation but I suppose it makes sense since you don't particularly care about the individual sizes. Please check it though.

Comment: That worked. Thank you for taking the time to help me!